# Smart Folder: how to create listing of all files in a folder?

Tags: smart-folders

I want to create a Smart Folder which just lists all files of my `~/Music` directory - i.e. just a flattened version of that folder.

How can I do this?

(I tried to type `*` in the search field, but that doesn't list all files.)

Comment: Are you looking for all files? Or just music/audio/video files? Do you want to exclude folders?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, the Spotlight GUI in the Finder will not let you use wildcards or other advanced syntax. However, by using the `Raw Query` search criterion, you can use all the syntax available to the command-line [`mdfind`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdfind.1.html) utility:

- Navigate to your ~/Music folder
- Hit ⌘ F
- Double-check the Scope Bar of the search to make sure Spotlight is just searching your Music folder
- Hit the "+" button to add a search criterion
- From the criteria drop-down menu, check if the `Raw Query` criterion is visible (it isn't by default). If not, click `Other...` and a criteria list will appear. Search for the `Raw Query` criterion, check the box to include it in the menu, and click "OK".
- Select the newly-visible `Raw Query` criterion and enter the following:

  ```
  (kMDItemFSName == '*.mp3') || (kMDItemFSName == '*.ogg') || (kMDItemFSName == '*.flac')
  ```

The above query will search for files that have .mp3, .ogg, or .flac in their filename (as opposed to the contents of the file). [This Macworld article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050427030707455) helped me construct this particular query, but [this Apple Developer page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/MDItemRef/Reference/reference.html) has a more comprehensive listing of the types of metadata available for raw queries.

---

Alternatively, you can construct the desired query visually:

[image: Spotlight query]

- Navigate to your ~/Music folder
- Hit ⌘ F
- Double-check the Scope Bar of the search to make sure Spotlight is just searching your Music folder
- Hit the "+" button to add a search criterion
- Choose the `Kind` criterion and set it to `Any`
- Hold down the `Option/Alt` key to create a conditional (thanks to [Adam Franco](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/28967/24289) for pointing this out) and set it to `Any`
- From the criteria drop-down menu, check if the `File extension` criterion is visible. If not, click `Other...` and a criteria list will appear. Search for the `File extension` criterion, check the box to include it in the menu, and click "OK".
- Add as many `File extension` criteria as you wish.

---

If you want the search to display **all files** below a given folder (regardless of file type), you can use the `File visibility` criterion:

- Navigate to your ~/Music folder
- Hit ⌘ F
- Double-check the Scope Bar of the search to make sure Spotlight is just searching your Music folder
- Hit the "+" button to add a search criterion
- From the criteria drop-down menu, check if the `File visibility` criterion is visible (it isn't by default). If not, click `Other...` and a criteria list will appear. Search for the `File invisible` criterion, check the box to include it in the menu, and click "OK".
- The `File visibility` option should now be in the search criterion drop-down menu. So long as this criterion is set to "Visible or Invisible", all files below the present folder will be shown (you can optionally change this to "Visible Items" you don't want dot-files in the results)

Comment: Can you explain why you chose "File visibility"?

Comment: Does it need at least one criteria or why did you add any? Why is that? Also, I thought about that and I tried with ["URL" and just set it to "contains `/`" but it didn't worked](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81913/smart-folder-what-is-the-url).

Comment: Also, I guess [placemarkers like `*` are not allowed?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81907/smart-folder-are-placemarkers-allowed-what-is-allowed)

Comment: How would I modify that if I would want to list exactly all `*.{mp3,ogg,flac}` files?

Comment: I chose the "File Visibility" criterion because it will display search results without entering text in the primary search field. Some criteria behave this way while others don't; this one seemed to be the quickest way to get all of the files listed below a given folder.

Comment: Do you have any reference why that criteria behaves that way and others don't?

Comment: Nothing beyond trial and error (I assume Apple makes a semantic judgement about whether a given criterion would need a string of characters to use along with the search). That said, after researching this some more, I believe I found a better way to do this and achieve the *.{mp3,ogg,flac} results you're looking for... an edit is forthcoming.

Comment: Answer has been updated to use the "Raw Query" criterion instead of "File visibility". I left the original answer to give context to the comment thread, but it's rather suboptimal for this question, so it could easily be removed.

Comment: I have updated the answer to provide a better way of constructing the query visually, so I went ahead and removed the original suboptimal answer.

Comment: Great answer. To clarify, does this, as the OP requested, recursively search subfolders?

Comment: You should add the "File Visibility" part to the answer again - in some cases, you might just want to list all files, of all kinds.

Comment: Yes, all these approaches search subfolders. Albert makes a good point re: the "File visibility" approach, so I've restored it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like just typing a . in the search field shows all files, but not folders.

Comment: Probably not the files which have no `.` in its name (i.e. no file extension). And probably it shows also the folders which have a `.` in its name.

Comment: Did you try it? I see files that don't contain periods, and I see no folders.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something, but this seems really simple:

- Navigate to your ~/Music folder
- Hit ⌘F
- Set to **Kind is Music**
- Click Save on the top right and you should be good to go.

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**
Here's v2 where I just set it to File Size is greater than 0KB and get all files in the Music folder
[image]

Comment: Kind is Music doesn't cover all music files for me (e.g. I think it's missing flac and ogg - see my [other question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81905/smart-folder-what-files-are-considered-as-music)) - anyway, in my question, I didn't specifically asked just for music files (whereby of course this was an interesting addition) but just for all files (as this might as well be interesting for other directories and `~/Music` was mostly just an example).

Comment: Change it to File Size is greater than 0KB and you get every file

Comment: Except the files which are empty?

Comment: What files are empty?  Even .DS_store has a size right?

Answer (score 0):

I know you want a smart folder, but in the absence of that, you can use Terminal:

ls -R ~/Music

This will give you a list, but I think what you want is to be able to see the files and access them directly.

Comment: And also sort them in varios ways - just everything what Finder can do in a single normal folder.